# TLSharp Connect Error

Tags: c#, telegram

Hi I am using TLSharp to send messages.

```
public async Task AuthUser()
    {
        var store = new FileSessionStore();
        var client = new TelegramClient(store, "session");

        await client.Connect(); // here my application stops and do nothing

        var hash = await client.SendCodeRequest(NumberToAuthenticate);
        var code = "93463"; // you can change code in debugger

        var user = await client.MakeAuth(NumberToAuthenticate, hash, code);


    }
```

I have replaced the apiHash and apiId in TelegramClient.cs file also.

Comment: Have you configured your Telegram account as outlined on their GitHub page

Comment: Yes i have configured as i have mentioned I have added apiHash and apiId in telegramCleint.cs file

Comment: I have this problem to... Somebody can help us?

Comment: @user3253756 what's error?